# IPv6 users see different site than IPv4 users

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6, ipv4

I had a site hosted on 1and1 that I moved to an Azure VM. I found that some people who have IPv6 enabled in their routers (not sure if that's the only situation but it's the one that I came across) are being sent to the site that was on 1and1.

The router I tested on had IPv6 enabled but I could still browse to sites that have only IPv4.

I had moved the site to Azure, changed the DNS, and it works perfectly but I also left the site folder on my 1and1 hosted package (I still have other sties hosted there) and that is what people are seeing.

Azure doesn't support IPv6 - they don't provide IPv6 addresses - so how can I ensure that people who have IPv6 enabled get to the correct site?

Thank you.

Comment: Moving from a provider with IPv6 support to a provider without it is a major step backwards.

Comment: @kasperd I think it depends highly what are real business needs on the ipv6, and if we like it or not. Good standards are imho good things, but the committees aren't really efficient to construct them (see Parkinson's Laws about this).

Comment: @peterh Google is seeing [steady growth](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html) in IPv6 usage. If you extrapolate from those numbers it will cross 50% in about three years. This [quote from facebook](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfjdOc41g0s) is also interesting: "we are seeing somewhere between 20 and 40 percent throughput improvement". It is quite clear that there currently is a percentage of users who are best served by IPv6 and in a few years that will be the majority of users.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 uses A records and IPv6 uses AAAA records so all you should have to do is delete the AAAA record in your DNS.